# The specified path `DemoView.podspec` does not point to an existing podspec file

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods

First time i am creating own CocoaPod, while pushing podspec using trunk to cocoapods,

```
pod trunk push DemoView.podspec
```

i am getting this error,
"[!] The specified path `DemoView.podspec` does not point to an existing podspec file."

what mistake i am doing,  anyone could help or suggest me to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did small mistake here, by this

```
$ pod trunk push [PATH]
```

i have given full path for podspec, finally that error gone.

Comment: what is [PATH] here?

Comment: the full path of your project file.

Answer (score 0):

Remove your path and the pod will deploy available *.podspec in your library folder to trunk.